# Best practice for cmake package dependency

Tags: cmake

I have two separate git repositories that I am not sure how to best bring together using cmake. I would like a solution that is cross platform.

I have a C++ library project which produces a static library (and C++ headers). This project has its own cmake which will produce a static library. I haven't yet written an install step in the cmake.

I have a UI (Qt) project which visualizes the product of this library. This also is based on cmake and should be using the library; in fact, it does not make sense without the library.

What is the best practice for a situation such as this? I could imagine a few things:

- The library is a git submodule of the UI project and the cmake of the UI uses `add_subdirectory()`
- The UI build expects the user to have built and installed (to the system) the static library & headers
- The UI build has a hard coded path (or ENV var) to the cmake of the library (or something like LibraryConfig.cmake, but I'm not familiar enough with this yet)

My end goal is that the user should be able to pull, build, and use the library in their own projects, but if in the future they feel necessary, they can grab the visualization tool additionally and use it with the library. Also, people who are not comfortable with using the library themselves might just want to clone the visualization tool repo and build & use it.

Comment: There is no "best" approach in a CMake project's organization. `find_package` approach could be used for 2 and 3 cases: by default, it searches the library only under system-wide locations, but it is possible to hint it with custom location. As for choosing between `add_subdirectory` and `find_package` approaches, both of them are good, there is no "best" of them. You may even support both of these approaches and choose the one based on an option.

Comment: You can also use [ExternalProject_add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#id6) directly with a Git repository. In this way Cmake will checkout the repository for you, without needing to use a git submodule.